# "O processo não pode acessar o arquivo porque ele está sendo usado por outro processo"

Tags: c#, exceção, io

Tenho uma classe que recupera dados de banco e guarda em um D.Reader, e escrevo cada registro em um arquivo de texto, nesse método:

```
 public void Escreve_Arquivos_Txt()
    {

        string folder = Program.caminhoAplicacao + @"\Serializer"; //Cria Pasta para Serialização           
        if (!Directory.Exists(folder))
        {
            Directory.CreateDirectory(folder);
        }
        int ContaArquivo = 0;
        int count = dataReader.FieldCount;
        using (file = new StreamWriter(Program.caminhoAplicacao + @"\Serializer\" + ContaArquivo + "Ser.txt"))
        {                
            while (this.dataReader.Read()) 
            {
                file.AutoFlush = true; // Limpa o buffer pra forçar a escrita
                for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
                {
                    file.WriteLine(this.dataReader.GetValue(i));
                }
                ContaArquivo++;
                file = new StreamWriter(Program.caminhoAplicacao + @"\Serializer\" + ContaArquivo + @"Ser.txt");
            }                                
        }
        file.Dispose();
    }
```

E tenho outro método pra ler esses arquivos, inserir em um d.table e apagar o que for sendo lido, nesse outro método:

```
private DataTable Preenche_Datatable(DataTable dataTable, int ContaArquivo, string diretorio, int quant_coluna)
    {
        do
        {
            int auxiliacount = quant_coluna - 1;
            int colunaIndex = 0;                
            string[] totaldelinhas = File.ReadAllLines(diretorio + ContaArquivo + "Ser.txt");
            DataRow dr = dataTable.NewRow();
            foreach (string contalinhas in totaldelinhas)
            {
                dr[colunaIndex] = contalinhas;
                if (colunaIndex == auxiliacount)
                {
                    dataTable.Rows.Add(dr);
                    dr = dataTable.NewRow();
                    colunaIndex = 0;
                }
                else
                {
                    colunaIndex++;
                }
            }
            File.Delete(diretorio + ContaArquivo + "Ser.txt");
            ContaArquivo++;
        }
        while (File.Exists(diretorio + ContaArquivo + "Ser.txt"));
        return dataTable;
    }
```

Vamos ao problema...
Ele escreve tudo tranquilo... Na hora de ler, de forma aleatória, alguns arquivos não são fechados e lançam a exceção de System.IO(*título da pergunta*) nessa linha:

```
string[] totaldelinhas = File.ReadAllLines(diretorio + ContaArquivo + "Ser.txt");
```

Já tentei usar Lock, synchronized, dispose do GC pra tentar isolar a thread/processo e não obtive sucesso.
Vale ressaltar que se eu executar os 2 métodos de forma separada, 1° executo o programa pra escrever fecho e depois abro pra ler, ele não lança essa exceção.
E também executei a leitura, pulando os que estavam sendo usados e não é uma cascata(Cascata no sentido de "aquele arquivo pra frente"), são arquivos aleatórios que continuam sendo "utilizados"... Já utilizei Close e Dispose individuais e juntos no primeiro método.

Aí vai o método de chamada caso necessário:

```
public DataTable Nova_Serializacao(DataTable dataTable)
    {
        Escreve_Arquivos_Txt();
        string dir = Program.caminhoAplicacao + @"\Serializer\"; 
        int count = dataReader.FieldCount;
        Recupera_Colunas(dataReader, count);
        int ContaArquivo = 0;            
        Preenche_Datatable(dataTable, ContaArquivo, dir, count);
        return dataTable;
    }
```

Alguém faz ideia do que possa ser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primeiro, quando se tem o [using](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-statement), não há necessidade de chamar o método `Dispose` em seguida do mesmo objeto.

> A instrução using **chama o método Dispose no objeto** da forma correta e ele também faz com que o objeto em si saia do escopo assim que Dispose é chamado. Dentro do bloco using, o objeto é somente leitura e não pode ser modificado ou reatribuído.

Então no seu código:

```
using (file = new StreamWriter(Program.caminhoAplicacao + @"\Serializer\" + ContaArquivo + "Ser.txt"))
{
    while (this.dataReader.Read())
    {
        file.AutoFlush = true; // Limpa o buffer pra forçar a escrita
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        {
file.WriteLine(this.dataReader.GetValue(i));
        }
        ContaArquivo++;
        file = new StreamWriter(Program.caminhoAplicacao + @"\Serializer\" + ContaArquivo + @"Ser.txt");
    }
}
file.Dispose(); //Esta chamada é desnecessária.
```

Esta chamada `file.Dispose();` pode ser removida (é redudante).

E em relação ao seu erro, acredito que o Reinaldo respondeu corretamente, você possui `StreamWriter` que não estão sendo fechados no método de escrita.

Observe, você cria um novo e não finaliza o antigo:

```
using (file = new StreamWriter(Program.caminhoAplicacao + @"\Serializer\" + ContaArquivo + "Ser.txt"))
{
    while (this.dataReader.Read())
    {
        file.AutoFlush = true; // Limpa o buffer pra forçar a escrita
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        {
file.WriteLine(this.dataReader.GetValue(i));
        }
        ContaArquivo++;

        //Nesta linha você cria uma nova instância do StreamWriter mas o anterior (o do loop atrás) não é fechado.
        file = new StreamWriter(Program.caminhoAplicacao + @"\Serializer\" + ContaArquivo + @"Ser.txt");
    }
}
```

Tente colocar o using dentro do loop, por exemplo:

```
while (this.dataReader.Read())
{
    using (var file = new StreamWriter(Program.caminhoAplicacao + @"\Serializer\" + ContaArquivo + "Ser.txt"))
    {
        file.AutoFlush = true; // Limpa o buffer pra forçar a escrita
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        {
            file.WriteLine(this.dataReader.GetValue(i));
        }
        ContaArquivo++;
    }
}
```

Desta forma, você garante que a cada loop será criado um novo `file` e o mesmo será "fechado" de forma correta.

Comment: Testei aqui, e de fato era isso.
Sobre o dispose e o using, era uma redundância intencional desesperada.

Comment: Muitíssimo agradecido

Answer (score 1):

Os seus `StreamWriters` estão ficando abertos, usa eles como variável/objeto e apos o uso invoca o método de fechamento `sw.Close()`

Comment: Já utilizei o Dispose e close no primeiro método que utiliza o Sw 
**.. Já utilizei Close e Dispose individuais e juntos no primeiro método.**
E no caso ele funciona pra uns e não funcionaria para os outros?

Comment: Além disso, to usando eles dentro de um Using que há um idisposable depois que sai do bloco, e reforcei dando um dispose depois que sai do bloco, e como disse, ja coloquei o close.

Comment: correção. De fato era aquilo, o amigo da outra resposta, me sinalizou de fato onde era, que eu não tive a mesma perspectiva.